Azure VM can't reach remote network with connected VPN
I have setup an Azure VPN gateway with a site to site VPN connection and the status of the VPN Connection is "Connected". I have also created an AKS cluster and an Azure VM in the same virtual network of the VPN Gateway. Now when I try to connect a remote ip address that is on the site in the remote network - it doesnt work - either from the Azure VM or the Azure VPN gateway. Ping or Tracert to the destination ip(NAT'ed ip address) doesnt work as well. Any ideas where the problem can be?
The output of netsh route
Publish  Type      Met  Prefix                    Idx  Gateway/Interface Name
-------  --------  ---  ------------------------  ---  ------------------------
No       Manual    0    0.0.0.0/0                  13  10.0.2.1
No       System    256  10.0.2.0/23                13  Ethernet
No       System    256  10.0.3.75/32               13  Ethernet
No       System    256  10.0.3.255/32              13  Ethernet
No       System    256  127.0.0.0/8                 1  Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1
No       System    256  127.0.0.1/32                1  Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1
No       System    256  127.255.255.255/32          1  Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1
No       Manual    1    168.63.129.16/32           13  10.0.2.1
No       Manual    1    169.254.169.254/32         13  10.0.2.1
No       System    256  224.0.0.0/4                 1  Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1
No       System    256  224.0.0.0/4                13  Ethernet
No       System    256  255.255.255.255/32          1  Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1
No       System    256  255.255.255.255/32         13  Ethernet


Any ideas where the problem can be? what route(es) does the host have to the remote network? Use route print.

0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         10.0.2.1        10.0.3.75     10
10.0.2.0    255.255.254.0         On-link         10.0.3.75    266
10.0.3.75  255.255.255.255         On-link         10.0.3.75    266
10.0.3.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         10.0.3.75    266

VNET : 10.0.0.0/24
akssubnet
10.0.2.0/23
GatewaySubnet
10.0.1.0/24

im able to ping the public ip of the Azure VPN gateway, but not the local vnet one(10.0.1.6).

Could you edit the question your question and add the output of netsh interface ipv4 show route and  netsh interface ipv6 show route from both endpoints?

@MirceaVutcovici updated the output

So this turned out to be the NAT issue on the VPN side and not related to the VM or the subnet. The tracert and ping still doesnt work but the TCP connection works once the NAT;ing issue on the VPN side was resolved.
